# How do you get the value of a static variable of a class from a list with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I have a javascript application which get's the data from a C#-WebMethod. The WebMethod returns a List of objects. The class of the obect has a static attribute and I will read this attibute in javascript. The code explains the problem probably better:

The Class:

```
public class DayEntryBT{
     public static string date { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     //some more...
}
```

The WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<DayEntryBT> getDayEntries()
{
    List<DayEntryBT> listOfEntries = new List<DayEntryBT>();
    //some sql...
    while (reader.Read()){
        DayEntryBT day = new DayEntryBT();
        DayEntryBT.date = reader["date"];
        day.name = reader["name"];
        listOfEntries.add(day);
    }
    return listOfEntries;
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DataProviderBT.asmx/getDayEntries",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resp) {
            alert(resp.d.date); //HOW TO GET THE STATIC ATTRIBUTE date HERE??????
            alert(resp.d[0].name); //THIS WORKS!!!
        }
    });
```

How can I get and set the value from the static attribute from javascript?

Regards

Comment: I would recommend getting fiddler and seeing what the return data looks like so you can better understand it.

Comment: your `d` is an array since you are returning a `List`, why wouldnt you access it through array notation?

Comment: I can access each element through a loop, but I cant access the static  attribute with it like resp.d[0].date

Comment: what are you using to encode the list to json? And does it encode static variables? Show an example of the returned json.

Comment: why in your webmethod code you use `date` not as static field?

Comment: It return an array of objects with __type "DayEntryBT" and all the normal attributes. I cant find the static attributes there, but if I send it back to a webservice I can read them out. I don't really encode them. Just access it like resp.d[0].name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround you can change your `DayEntryBT` class like this

```
public class DayEntryBT{
    public static string StaticDate { get; set; }
    public string date {get { return StaticDate; }}
    public string name { get; set; }
    //some more...
}
```

and after you can get it like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DataProviderBT.asmx/getDayEntries",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp.d[0].date); //this works, with value of static field
        ....
    }
});
```

also you can see about custom serializer.